# Eclipse PDT - change font color of CSS Content Assist

Tags: css, eclipse, eclipse-pdt

Where to change font color of CSS Content Assist in Eclipse PDT. Which parameter it is?

[image]

As displayed on the screenshot, I need to change the white font color on white background.

Answer (score 0):

Found myself

Options - Editors - Structured Text Editors - Appearance - Completion Proposal Foreground.